# archivos, guardar arreglo de objetos en un archivo, c++

Tags: c++

Tengo un programa que crea un arreglo de objetos y quiero guardar los datos que genere en un archivo, pero no logro figurar como hacerlo, se como crear un archivo simple, de unas cuantas lineas de texto, el problema es aplicarlo a este programa

por ejemplo, con el programa creo dos objetos con todos los datos que pide, lo que sigue es que esos datos que ingrese se guarden en un archivo de texto.

de antemano muchas gracias <2+1

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

class Estudiante{
    private:
        string nombre;
        int matricula;
    public:
        Estudiante();
        Estudiante(string name, int mat);
        string getNombre();
        int getMatricula();
        void mostrarEstudiante();
};

Estudiante::Estudiante(){
    nombre = "unknow";
    matricula = 0; 
}

Estudiante::Estudiante(string name, int mat){
    nombre = name;
    matricula = mat;
}

string Estudiante::getNombre(){
    return nombre;
}

int Estudiante::getMatricula(){
    return matricula;
}

void Estudiante::mostrarEstudiante(){
    cout<<"Datos del Estudiante."<<endl;
    cout<<"nombre: "<<getNombre()<<" "<<getApellido()<<endl;
    cout<<"matricula: "<<getMatricula()<<endl;
}


int main(){
    int n;
    cout<<"digite el numero de estudiantes: ";
    cin>>n;
    Estudiante e[n];
    string name;
    int mat;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<"\nDa el nombre del estudiante: ";
        cin>>name;
        cout<<"\nDa la matricula: ";
        cin>>mat;
       e[i]=Estudiante(name,mat);
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder realizar lo que mencionas, de guardar la información de tu arreglo en un archivo de texto,  solo sería necesario agregar esta función "CrearArchivo" que te comparto a tu código. En la cuál se necesitan dos parámetros, un arreglo y un entero que sería el tamaño de tu arreglo.

```
void CrearArchivo(Estudiante estudiantes[], int n) {

    ofstream fs("Estudiantes.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        fs << "Nombre: " << estudiantes[i].getNombre() << endl;
        fs << "Matricula: " << estudiantes[i].getMatricula() << "\n" << endl;   
    }
    fs.close();}
```

Este es un ejemplo de como quedaría tu función main:

```
int main() {
    int n;
    cout << "digite el numero de estudiantes: ";
    cin >> n;
    Estudiante e[n];
    string name;
    int mat;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "\nDa el nombre del estudiante: ";
        cin >> name;
        cout << "\nDa la matricula: ";
        cin >> mat;
        e[i] = Estudiante(name, mat);
    }

    CrearArchivo(e, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Espero que te haya sido útil.

Comment: muchas gracias, si funciono :)